# Как адаптировать этот код под разрешения?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

я не совсем понимаю как мне адаптировать свой код, когда у меня в полноэкранном режиме, то все выглядит нормально, но когда я перехожу в режим "окно" наполнение сайта не адаптируется под данное окно, также при открытии сайта на другом устройстве с другим разрешением экрана, сайт также не адаптируется под это разрешение. Я немного решил проблему, добавив горизонтальный ползунок, но хотелось бы, чтобы сайт адаптировался под разрешения, без использования этого ползунка, может я не правильно использую медиа-запрос или что-то другое.
Вот сам код:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    font-size: 16px; /* Базовый размер шрифта */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
    main {
        right:100px;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    .v40_1191{
       word-wrap: normal;
    }
    .v40_1192{
        word-wrap: normal;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
    body {
        font-size:12px;
        overflow-x:scroll ;
    }
    .v40_1191{
       word-wrap: normal;
    }
    .v40_1192{
        word-wrap: normal;
    }
}

main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.v40_1181 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh; 
  background: url("../images/v40_1181.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.v40_1182 {
  width: 180px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 336px;
  left: 750px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Bold;
  font-size: 61px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.v40_1191 {
    width: 1450px;
    height: 526px;
    background: url("../images/v40_1191.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 908px;
    left: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1192 {
    width: 1450px;
    height: 526px;
    background: url("../images/v40_1192.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1193 {
    width: 375px;
    color: rgba(54,110,182,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 535px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: Bold;
    font-size: 48px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.v40_1194 {
    width: 492px;
    height: 455px;
    background: url("../images/v40_1194.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: -72px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1195 {
    width: 492px;
    height: 455px;
    background: rgba(235,233,233,1);
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 13px;
    border-top-right-radius: 13px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
    box-shadow: 2.625px 3.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1196 {
    width: 347px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 214px;
    left:72px;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-weight: Semibold;
    font-size: 21px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: left;
}
.v40_1197 {
    width: 1450px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 91px;
    left: 515px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: Regular;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: left;
}
.v40_2222{
    width: 1450px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 86px;
    left: 0px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: Regular;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: left;
}
.v40_1198 {
    width: 1450px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 290px;
    left: 515px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: Regular;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: left;
}
.v40_1111{
    width: 863px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: Regular;
    font-size: 17px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: left;
    top:285px;
    left:0px;
}
.v40_1199 {
  width: 1450px;
  height: 751px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1199.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1540px;
  left: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1200 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 674px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1200.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 81px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1201 {
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: SemiBold;
  font-size: 26px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1202 {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 100px;
  left:0px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.Let{
  width:100%;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
  font-size:26px;
  
}
.v40_1203 {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 197px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1204 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 296px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1205 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 396px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1206 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 496px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1207 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 595px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1208 {
  width: 367px;
  color: rgba(54,110,182,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 542px;
  font-weight: Bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1209 {
  width: 239px;
  height: 27px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1209.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: 184px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1210 {
  width: 85px;
  height: 45px;
  background: rgba(4,74,164,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 1410px;
  border-top-left-radius: 17px;
  border-top-right-radius: 17px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1211 {
  width: 27px;
  height: 19px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1211.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1212 {
  width: 21px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 7px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1213 {
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1213.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1214 {
  width: 9px;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.v40_1215 {
  width: 19px;
  height: 10px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1215.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1216 {
  width: 19px;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgba(245,245,245,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1217 {
  width: 19px;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1247 {
  width: 1680px;
  height: 218px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1247.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2396px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1248 {
  width: 1680px;
  height: 218px;
  background: rgba(244,244,244,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1249 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 162px;
  left: 665px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1250 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1250.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1251 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1251.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1252 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1252.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1253 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: rgba(46,46,46,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.v40_1254 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1254.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1255 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.v40_1256 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 3px;
}
.v40_1257 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 127px;
  left: 665px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1258 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1258.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1259 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1259.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1260 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1260.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1261 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 9px;
  background: rgba(46,46,46,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 5px;
}
.v40_1262 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: rgba(46,46,46,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.v40_1263 {
  width: 129px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 94px;
  left: 692px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1264 {
  width: 102px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 129px;
  left: 692px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1265 {
  width: 102px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 164px;
  left: 692px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1266 {
  width: 77px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 59px;
  left: 665px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1267 {
  width: 227px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 59px;
  left: 1069px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1268 {
  width: 262px;
  height: 29px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1268.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52px;
  left: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1269 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: rgba(249,193,50,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 92px;
  left: 665px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1270 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 12px;
  background: rgba(46,46,46,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0px;
}
.v40_1271 {
  width: 262px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 104px;
  left: 140px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1272 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: rgba(46,46,46,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  left: 1106px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8749px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8749px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8749px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8749px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1273 {
  width: 7px;
  height: 13px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1273.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 9px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1274 {
  width: 6px;
  height: 13px;
  background: rgba(237,237,237,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 1px;
}
.v40_1275 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: rgba(46,46,46,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  left: 1069px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8749px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8749px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8749px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8749px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1276 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 15px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1276.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1277 {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  background: rgba(237,237,237,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 3px;
}
.v40_1398 {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1398.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 39px;
  left: 768px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1399 {
  width: 104px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 127px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1400 {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: url("../images/v40_1400.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v40_1401 {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 8;
  width: 48px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

.v40_1403 {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 8;  
  width: 104px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 127px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1404 {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 8;  
  width: 81px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 309px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v40_1405 {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 8;  
  width: 68px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 469px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./MW2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>MW</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="v40_1181">
            <span class="v40_1182">O nas</span>
          </div>
          <div class="v40_1191">
            <div class="v40_1192">
                <span class="v40_1193">Nasza historia</span>
                <div class="v40_1194">
                    <div class="v40_1195">

                    </div>
                    <span class="v40_1196">Photo of someone from company</span>
                </div>
                <span class="v40_1197">Witamy w MW-Grains, zaufanym przewodniku po świecie wysokiej jakości produktów <br> spożywczych. Od 2000 roku staliśmy się symbolem niezawodności i jakości w handlu, a dziś z <br> dumą świętujemy 20. rok naszej udanej działalności.<br>
                <span class="v40_2222">Nasza historia rozpoczęła się w 2000 roku, kiedy zrealizowaliśmy naszą pierwszą transakcję. <br> Ten ważny moment był punktem wyjścia naszej podróży w świecie żywności. Tego dnia, w omszałym <br> biurze, zawarliśmy pierwszą umowę, która stała się fundamentem do zbudowania naszej firmy.<br><br><br></span></span>
                <span class="v40_1198">Ta pierwsza transakcja nie była tylko wymianą produktów - była to wymiana pomysłów, wartości i <br> aspiracji do stworzenia czegoś wyjątkowego. Włożyliśmy w to nie tylko nasz produkt, ale także <br> kawałek naszej duszy, wnosząc kreatywność i zaangażowanie w doskonałość na każdym kroku.<br><br>
                <span class="v40_1111">Od tego czasu MW-Grains stała się nie tylko firmą, ale rodziną zjednoczoną wspólnym celem, jakim <br> jest dostarczanie naszym klientom produktów o wyjątkowej jakości. Staliśmy się organizacją z <br> ogromnym doświadczeniem handlowym i każdego dnia uczymy się i rozwijamy, aby oferować <br> klientom to, co najlepsze w świecie żywności.</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="v40_1199">
                <div class="v40_1200">
                    <span class="v40_1201">Zaufaj doświadczeniu, jakości i dbałości o szczegóły - wybierz współpracę z MW-Grains. Nie jesteśmy tylko <br>firmą, jesteśmy standardem doskonałości w świecie żywności i dlatego nie będziesz chciał przegapić okazji<br> do współpracy z nami:</span>
                    <span class="v40_1202"><span class="Let">20 lat udanej działalności:</span><br>
                    "MW-Grains jest dumny ze swojego 20-letniego doświadczenia w handlu żywnością. To stuletnie doświadczenie stało się naszym głównym atutem, gwarancją współpracy z wiarygodnym i dojrzałym partnerem.</span>
                    <span class="v40_1203"><span>Szeroka gama produktów:</span><br>
                    Nasz katalog produktów reprezentuje różnorodność smaków i jakości. Od świeżego oleju słonecznikowego po delikatną mąkę pszenną i krystalicznie czysty cukier - oferujemy produkty dla najbardziej wyrafinowanych gustów.</span>
                    <span class="v40_1204"><span>Kreatywne podejście do biznesu:</span><br>
                    Nie jesteśmy zwykłymi sprzedawcami, jesteśmy twórcami pysznych chwil. Nasze kreatywne podejście do biznesu nadaje każdemu <br> produktowi unikalny charakter i rozpoznawalny styl, dzięki czemu współpraca z nami jest wyjątkowym doświadczeniem.</span>
                    <span class="v40_1205"><span>Zaufane relacje:</span><br>
                    "MW-Grains" buduje nie tylko transakcje biznesowe, ale także długoterminowe relacje. Cenimy każdego klienta, jesteśmy gotowi uważnie wysłuchać jego potrzeb i dostosować się do jego wymagań.</span>
                    <span class="v40_1206"><span>Najwyższy standard jakości:</span><br>
                    Nasza firma jest dostawcą najwyższej klasy produktów. Śledzimy każdy etap produkcji, aby mieć pewność, że każdy produkt, który do Ciebie trafia, spełnia nasze standardy jakości.</span>
                    <span class="v40_1207"><span>Innowacja i wzrost:</span><br>
                    "MW-Grains nieustannie poszukuje nowych możliwości i innowacji w świecie żywności. Współpraca z nami oznacza, że zawsze jesteś o krok<br> do przodu, gotowy zaoferować swoim klientom coś wyjątkowego i istotnego".</span>
                </div>
                <span class="v40_1208">Kim jesteśmy?</span>
            </div>
            <div class="v40_1209">

            </div>
            <div class="v40_1210">
                <div class="v40_1211">
                    <span class="v40_1212">PL</span>
                    <div class="v40_1213">
                        <div class="v40_1214">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="v40_1215">
                    <div class="v40_1216">

                    </div>
                    <div class="v40_1217">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="v40_1247">
                <div class="v40_1248">

                </div>
                <div class="v40_1249">
                    <div class="v40_1250">
                        <div class="v40_1251">
                            <div class="v40_1252">
                                <div class="v40_1253">

                                </div>
                                <div class="v40_1254">
                                    <div class="v40_1255">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="v40_1256">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="v40_1257">
                    <div class="v40_1258">
                        <div class="v40_1259">
                            <div class="v40_1260">
                                <div class="v40_1261">

                                </div>
                                <div class="v40_1262">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="v40_1263">info@mw-grains.eu</span>
                <span class="v40_1264">+48 535 251 380</span>
                <span class="v40_1265">+48 535 251 380</span>
                <span class="v40_1266">KONTAKT</span>
                <span class="v40_1267">MEDIA SPOŁECZNOŚCIOWE</span>
                <div class="v40_1268">

                </div>
                <div class="v40_1269">
                    <div class="v40_1270">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="v40_1271">Adres: ul. Aleja Jerozolimskia 89/43, 02-001 Warszawa, Polska</span>
                <div class="v40_1272">
                    <div class="v40_1273">
                        <div class="v40_1274">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="v40_1275">
                    <div class="v40_1276">
                        <div class="v40_1277">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="v40_1398">
                <div class="v40_1400">
                    <span class="v40_1401">O nas</span>
                    <span class="v40_1403">działalność</span>
                    <span class="v40_1404">produkty</span>
                    <span class="v40_1405">KONtakt</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Значения на подобии `width` `top` нужно указывать в единицах зависящих от размера экрана (к примеру в %)

Comment: То есть мне каждый width top в проценты перевести? Или как?

Comment: Можно указывать размеры в media если для элемента неважно плавное изменение размера в зависимости от размера экрана.

Comment: Я правильно понял?:@media screen and (max-width:100%){}

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 500px)` - все размеры экрана больше 500px 

`@media screen and (max-width: 500px)` - все размеры экрана меньше 500px

Comment: Точно также, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Если у Вас `width, height, top, left` и так далее указано в пикселях, Вы какой-то магии ожидаете или как? Что какой-то элемент с шириной `width: 1450px;` на мобильном телефоне как-то сам перестроится, это ведь так не работает. Почитайте для начала какие-то базовые вещи [Responsive design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design). В остальном все выглядит как сгенерированый код, потому что он не слишком читаем и не то чтобы был хорош, почти все висит на абсолюте, даже пункты меню, по какой-то причине.

Comment: Я ж делаю сейчас версию для компьютера, а для мобильной отдельно

Comment: @Илья так а в чем вопрос тогда?